# SqlDependency with SQL Cluster?

Tags: .net, sql-server, cluster-computing, sqldependency

I have a short question about SqlDependency. I have two SQL 2005 servers configured in a failover cluster..

When the active node is changed I stop receiving notifications... i have to manually restart the windows service that hosts the SqlDependency...

Is this the correct behavior? How can i automatically restart the dependency??

Thanks in advance!!

ps. sorry my english sucks! cheers from argentina!!!

Answer (score 0):

It is expected behavior as explained here - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/930048.

As it states:

> To resolve this issue, add code to monitor database mirroring failovers. Then, re-execute the relevant commands that are used together with the dependencies.

You might find post ["How to Detect Database Mirroring Failovers"](http://bobhl.blogspot.com/2011/08/how-to-detect-database-mirroring.html) useful. It shows different ways to monitor failovers.